# What is this bulb with pink single flowers and glossy strap-like leaves?

Tags: identification, flowers, tropical

I live in Sri Lanka. But this is not a local plant. Can anyone point out the name of the plant of this flower. The leaves of the plants are pointed with red arrows. The leaves of the plant are only the ones pointed with red arrow. 
Leaf is just grass like thick thin max 15 cm long kind of.

I forgot to mention each has two or 2 leaves long like I mentioned above. Each plant is having a bulb like red onion, but much smaller in size and unlike red onion this bulb is more white like in color.

[image]

Comment: Welcome chathwind! I like your red arrows! That's a lovely flower. Is it growing on individual grassy plants, or is it like a vine or groundcover, with flowers scattered around? Have you seen something similar in any other colors?

Comment: I'm not familiar with most Sri Lanka plants, but it looks like a bulb/corm of some kind.. What habitat was it in? lawn? Woodland?

Comment: @Sue I'm so sorry about my late reply, it grows like ground cover but flowers come occasionally, not everyday you see flowers. One my friend said this same plant is having white flower (just the color is the difference, flower is very same) variety too.

Comment: @J.Musser I think this is not a local species, because my grand father bought it from a garden store long time before. Didn't know the name. It was in our garden for years, but no one didn't know the name. Forgot to mention yes it has bulbs like onions but smaller than onion and color is more white like not like onion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

J. Musser 's comment gave me a new clue to find it. I Googled tropical garden plants with bulbs, here I saw the flower in one article it gave me. Furthermore I searched and found it's what I was looking for. The name of the plant is **Zephyranthes carinata** , which is known as **rosepink zephyr lily** or **pink rain lily**. Here's the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zephyranthes_carinata) article about it. 
Furthermore I found this picture, it gives an idea about the plant more than my picture. [image]
Thanks to you all for your kind help.

Comment: I'm glad you found the identity of your plant, and posted it so we can all learn! Please come on back with any questions about your garden, or to answer other questions you find Interesting!